# create folder inside S3 bucket using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I'm able to create an S3 bucket using cloudformation but would like to create a folder inside an S3 bucket..like

```
<mybucket>--><myfolder>
```

Please let me know the template to be used to create a folder inside a bucket ...both should be created at the sametime...

I'm Using AWS lambda as below

```
stackname = 'myStack'
client = boto3.client('cloudformation')
response = client.create_stack(
    StackName= (stackname),
    TemplateURL= 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/<myS3bucket>/<myfolder>/nestedstack.json',
    Parameters=<params>
)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

AWS doesn't provide an official CloudFormation resource to create objects within an S3 bucket. However, you can create a [Lambda-backed Custom Resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources-lambda.html) to perform this function using the AWS SDK, and in fact the [gilt/cloudformation-helpers](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers#put-s3-objects) GitHub repository provides an off-the-shelf custom resource that does just this.

As with any Custom Resource setup is a bit verbose, since you need to first deploy the Lambda function and IAM permissions, then reference it as a custom resource in your stack template.

First, add the `Lambda::Function` and associated `IAM::Role` resources to your stack template:

```
"S3PutObjectFunctionRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": [ "lambda.amazonaws.com" ]
          },
          "Action": [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "ManagedPolicyArns": [
      { "Ref": "RoleBasePolicy" }
    ],
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "S3Writer",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version" : "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
              ],
              "Resource": "*"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
"S3PutObjectFunction": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": "com.gilt.public.backoffice",
      "S3Key": "lambda_functions/cloudformation-helpers.zip"
    },
    "Description": "Used to put objects into S3.",
    "Handler": "aws/s3.putObject",
    "Role": {"Fn::GetAtt" : [ "S3PutObjectFunctionRole", "Arn" ] },
    "Runtime": "nodejs",
    "Timeout": 30
  },
  "DependsOn": [
    "S3PutObjectFunctionRole"
  ]
},
```

Then you can use the Lambda function as a Custom Resource to create your S3 object:

```
"MyFolder": {
  "Type": "Custom::S3PutObject",
  "Properties": {
    "ServiceToken": { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["S3PutObjectFunction", "Arn"] },
    "Bucket": "mybucket",
    "Key": "myfolder/"
  }
},
```

You can also use the same Custom Resource to write a string-based S3 object by adding a `Body` parameter in addition to `Bucket` and `Key` (see the [docs](https://github.com/gilt/cloudformation-helpers#put-s3-objects)).

Answer (score 24):

This is not possible using an AWS CloudFormation template.

It should be mentioned that **folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3**. Instead, the path of an object is prepended to the name (`key`) of an object.

So, file `bar.txt` stored in a folder named `foo` is actually stored with a Key of: `foo/bar.txt`

You can also copy files to a folder that doesn't exist and the folder will be automatically created (which is not actually true, since the folder itself doesn't exist). However, the Management Console will provide the appearance of such a folder and the path will suggest that it is stored in such a folder.

**Bottom line:** There is no need to pre-create a folder. Just use it as if it were already there.

Comment: actually i need to invoke cloudformation jsons placed inside a folder under S3 bucket from a Lambda function...so where should i place my jsons if folder is not required to be created upfront???

Comment: Could you please provide more information about your actual requirements (eg what do you mean by "invoke cloudformation jsons")? Best way is to update the original Question with an example of what you have tried and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: Updated my question please check!!!..Im trying to create multiple resources (SNS,EC2 etc..) using AWS lambda which invokes create_stack api wherein nestedstack.json is one of the parameter....

Comment: I want to place nestedstack.json inside a folder which is in an s3 bucket

Comment: You haven't explained HOW you intend to put the file there, but the answer is... put it there! If you copy a file to the bucket with a path like "templates/nestedstack.json", then that becomes the name (Key) of the Object. It "looks" like it's in a folder but it isn't. There's no need to pre-create the folder -- simply store the file and it will work.

Comment: I want to upload file manually but before that folder should exist right?? I mean only  uploading file should be a manual step where bucket and folder should be created using cloud formation...

Comment: I got a region error with this. The README says to use "S3Bucket": "com.gilt.public.backoffice.<YOUR REGION>",

Comment: @Julian Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I wasn't asking a new question just pointing out that there may be missing information in this answer - the question doesn't specify the a region. So the OP may be have been in any region.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot (at least as of now) create a sub folder inside s3 bucket.

You can try using following command :

```
 aws s3 mb s3://yavdhesh-bucket/inside-folder
```

And then try to list all the folders inside the bucket using command:

```
aws s3 ls s3://yavdhesh-bucket
```

And you will observe that the sub folder was not created.

there is only one way to create a subfolder, that is by creating/copying a file inside a non-existing sub folder or sub directory (with respect to bucket)

For example,

```
aws s3 cp demo.txt s3://yavdhesh-bucket/inside-folder/
```

Now if you list down the files present inside your sub-folder, it should work.

```
 aws s3 ls s3://yavdhesh-bucket/inside-folder/
```

it should list down all the files present in this sub folder.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a small python script. It should be run manually, but it does the the sync automatically. It's for lazy people who don't want to create a Lambda-Backed Custom Resource.

```py
import subprocess
import json

STACK_NAME = ...
S3_RESOURCE = <name of your s3 resource, as in CloudFormation template file>
LOCAL_DIR = <path of your local dir>

res = subprocess.run(
    ['aws', 'cloudformation', 'describe-stack-resource', '--stack-name', STACK_NAME, '--logical-resource-id', S3_RESOURCE],
    capture_output=True,
)
out = res.stdout.decode('utf-8')
resource_details = json.loads(out)
resource_id = resource_details['StackResourceDetail']['PhysicalResourceId']

res = subprocess.run(
    ['aws', 's3', 'sync', LOCAL_DIR, f's3://{resource_id}/', '--acl', 'public-read']
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by *wjordan* to gilt/cloudformation-helpers doesn't work anymore.

This KB from AWS Knowledge Center outlines how to do it via both JSON or YAML templates:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-s3-custom-resources/

Note this little line:

> Note: In the following resolution, all the S3 bucket content is
> deleted when the CloudFormation stack is deleted.