# How can i create s3 bucket and object (like upload an shell script file) pro grammatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud

I have to do this for almost 100 account so planning to create using something infra as code. Cloud formation does not support creating object.. can anyone help

Answer (score 0):

There are several strategies, depending on the client environment.

The aws-cli may be used for shell scripting, aws-sdk for JavaScript environments, or Boto3 for python environments.

If you provide the client environment, creating an S3 object is almost a one-liner holding equal s3 bucket security and lifecycle matters.

Comment: Yup.. understood, But need to create something similar to Cloud formation.. so my operational team can use it..As my complete requirement is to setup few IAM roles, Create S3 bucket with a object file into it and an lambda.. all these should go in one..

Comment: CloudFormation largely declares the infrastructure, and not the data that goes into it.  So this is likely why CloudFormation is not enabling your inclusion of the S3 bucket objects when using CloudFormation to set up a stack.  So you will need some type of hook.  For example, you can create a lambda and then have it do the object creation and then include that lambda as a custom resource in the cloudformation stack.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917947/create-folder-inside-s3-bucket-using-cloudformation for an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Rich Andrew said, there are several different technologies. If you are trying to do infrastructure as code and attach policies and roles I would suggest you look into Terraform or Serverless.

Comment: Okay let me check terraform .. i haven't explored it yet.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I frequently combine two of the techniques already mentioned above.

For infrastructure setup - Terraform. This tool is always ahead of competition (Ansible, etc.) in terms of cloud modules. You can use it to create bucket, create bucket policies, users, their IAM policies for bucket access, upload initial files to bucket and much more.
It will keep state file containing record of those resources, so you can use the same workflow to destroy all that's created if necessary with very little modifications.
Very easy to get started, but not flexible and you can be caught out if scope change in middle of project suddenly requires feature that's not there.
To get started check out Terrafrom module registry - https://registry.terraform.io/.
It has quite a few S3 modules available to get started even quicker.

For interaction with aws resources - Python Boto3. In your case that would be subsequent file uploads, deletions in S3 bucket.
You can use Boto3 to set up infrastructure - just like Terraform, but it will require more work on your side (like handling exceptions and errors).